# iframe control goes to another website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Website</h1><br>
        <iframe class="markItUpPreviewFrame" width="1000" height="2000" src="http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://axattechnologies.com/" target="_blank"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have opened archive.org website in iframe. After click on any link in the iframe the control goes to the  archive.org.
But I want after, after click on link the new page open in new tab.
Means any link open in new tab. Any solution using jquery or javascript.

Comment: Can't be done if the website you're embedding doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how iframes work. They are *someone else's webpage*, embedded in yours. You don't get informed about what users do on that webpage, because if you were, you could intercept everything they did: check the passwords they type, check the things they click, etc. etc. Unless the webpage that's loaded into the iframe has its server set to specifically allow your webpage access via iframes, you don't get access to what happens inside of it.

It sounds like you're actually trying to do something else, the solution for which you thought would be iframes. I can recommend starting a new question asking about how to do what you wanted to do, rather than asking about how to circumvent iframe security =)